# why sql command cannot be converted to mysql command in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am currently working on connecting my data grid view to my database, but the problem is I can't connect with this error : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

here's my code:

```
Private Sub populateGird()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim bs As New BindingSource
        Try
            sqlC = New MySqlCommand("SELECT c_id, CONCAT(c_firstname, c_lastname), rank_name, c_bir_status, rank_basic_pay, rank_positional_allowance," &
                                    "rank_meal_allowance, ca_worth FROM tbl_crew, tbl_cash_advance, tbl_rank", conn)
            da.SelectCommand = sqlC '--> error is that sqlC
            da.Fill(ds)
            bs.DataSource = ds
            PayrollGrid.DataSource = bs
            da.Update(ds)
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

this is my connection code in a module:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module Module1
Public conn As MySqlConnection

Public Sub connect()
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=fat2x_payroll;pwd=;Convert Zero Datetime=True"

    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: either change your command to be a SQLCommand, or change your SQLDataAdapter to a MySQLDataAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear - you are trying to assign from an incompatible type! `SelectCommand` is of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` because you have defined `da` as a variable of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter`. On the other hand, you are creating a variable of type `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand`, which is a different type and which cannot be converted to `SqlCommand` when you try to do the assignment.

The way to fix this is to change your code to use the corresponding classes from `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, like so:

```
 Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration of the SqlDataAdapter to the appropriate type for MySQL (I'm guessing MySqlDataAdapter?)

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
```