# Unable to create a connection between Visual Studio 2010 amd MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, database-connection

I have been trying to connect visual studio and mysql for a while now but have failed.
On executing the following code, I am getting this error: **error BC30311: Value of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Partial Class AddStock
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim myConnectionString As String

    myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;" _
                & "uid=root;" _
                & "pwd=12345;" _
                & "database=test;"

    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
        conn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into records ([p_id], [pname], [powner], [quantity], [threshold], [e_id]) values ('" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "')", conn)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Inserted")

    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: When you are connecting to a different type of database you have to get the driver to connect. See that  ODBC driver is available at www.mysql.com/products/connector/odbc.

Comment: What changes am I supposed to make to the code once I download the above?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28206058 for related issue with mismatches

Comment: You need to install driver with the system where you are executing this code.Then re-run the code and you should be fine, see if code generates any error then you need to further look into code related issue.